# How to store values into database after retrieving from database placing checkbox before each row?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

My code retrieves some values from database and displays in a table. Before each row I am placing a checkbox such that when it is checked that value can be stored in database. Each row contains four columns. It may retrieve several rows. If I select few rows then these rows should be store into database.

```
 <table border='0' align="center">
    <tr class="db_table_tr3" >
      <th class="db_table_th3" > </th>
      <th class="db_table_th3" >Course Code</th>
      <th class="db_table_th3" >Course Name</th>
      <th class="db_table_th3" >Instructor</th>
      <th class="db_table_th3" >Credit</th>
    </tr>
    <?php

            $query = "select *from course_details WHERE branch='$branch' AND sem='$sem'";

            $run = mysql_query($query) or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error()); 
            $num = mysql_numrows($run);


            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)){

                echo "<tr >";
                echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="ticked[]" value="' . $row['course_codes'] . '"></td>'; 
        //      echo "<td>" . $row['usn'] . "</a>" . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['course_codes'] . " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['course_names'] . " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['course_instructors'] . " </td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['course_credits'] . " </td>";

            }   
            echo "</tr>";
```

now i want to store the first column as follows

```
$ch1=$_POST['ticked']; 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof(ch1); $i++){
     here is the query
    }
}
```

does the above code is correct. how to store values of all columns in different tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting a value for 'course_codes' in checkbox use 'course_details' table primary key. So you can retrieve data according to the primary key on a post page and insert a record as per your requirement. Secondly you can make an array of hidden variables and do the insertion part

Comment: ...say the primary key is cc_id then i need to replace course_codes by cc_id...am i right?

Comment: Yes and get a record according to the cc_id on a post page(from same table course_details) and insert it in a different table as per your requirement